# Building assimp on Win32 (Visual Studio 2019 x86)

Tags: cmake, assimp, ros2

I'm trying to build ROS2 for Win32 and one of the packages imports and builds assimp. Currently I'm having issues with files in the contrib/unzip folder with a lot of syntax errors (see build output below). I guess I need to set the correct compiler version somewhere but I don't know which C compiler is needed or if I need to modifiy/ update the unzip code. Until now I've tried to set different `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` (which should be irrelevant because unzip only contains C code...right?) in assimp's CMakeList but I didn't get anywhere with that.
I'm compiling assimp in a Visual Studio 2019 x86 Command Prompt with the cmake flag `-A Win32`. Full command is `colcon build --cmake-args -A WIN32 --packages-select rviz_assimp_vendor`.

I'd be glad about any help on this issues because, to be honest, I've only used rather simple CMakeLists in the ROS and ROS2 environment so I don't really know how to move forward.

```
cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
  ioapi.c
  unzip.c
  zip.c
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(150,18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(150,18): error C2059: syntax error: '*' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(152,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(35,60): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(35,60): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(35,73): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(36,1): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'pcrc_32_tab' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(48,58): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(48,58): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(48,76): error C2059: syntax error: 'type' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(48,77): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(65,76): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(65,76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(65,89): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\crypt.h(66,1): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'pcrc_32_tab' (compiling source file C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c) [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(401,11): error C2065: 'unz_s': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(401,11): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'us' [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(401,13): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(402,11): error C2065: 'unz_s': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(402,13): error C2065: 's': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(419,32): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(419,33): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(419,28): error C2198: 'fill_fopen_filefunc': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(421,11): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(421,12): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,7): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,8): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,25): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,26): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,52): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(423,53): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(427,11): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(427,12): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(430,48): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(430,49): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(430,62): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(430,63): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(430,44): error C2198: 'unzlocal_SearchCentralDir': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(435,1): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(435,1): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(435,1): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(439,29): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(439,30): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(439,44): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(439,45): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(439,25): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getLong': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(443,30): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(443,31): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(443,45): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(443,46): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(443,26): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getShort': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(447,30): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(447,31): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(447,45): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(447,46): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(447,26): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getShort': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,30): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,31): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,45): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,46): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,60): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,61): error C2224: left of '.gi' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(451,26): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getShort': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(455,30): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(455,31): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(455,45): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(455,46): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(455,26): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getShort': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(458,29): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(458,30): error C2224: left of '.gi' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,29): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,30): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,44): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,45): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,59): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,60): error C2224: left of '.size_central_dir' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(464,25): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getLong': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,29): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,30): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,44): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,45): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,59): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,60): error C2224: left of '.offset_central_dir' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(469,25): error C2198: 'unzlocal_getLong': too few arguments for call [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,30): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,31): error C2224: left of '.z_filefunc' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,45): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,46): error C2224: left of '.filestream' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,60): error C2065: 'us': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0\contrib\unzip\unzip.c(473,61): error C2224: left of '.gi' must have struct/union type [C:\dev\ros2_foxy_custom\build\rviz_assimp_vendor\assimp-4.1.0-prefix\src\assimp-4.1.0-build\code\assimp.vcxproj]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building Assimp 4.0.x with VS2019 is not supported. To work with it you have to switch to the latest release 5.0.1. Then the build should work.